# the way to get a datetime from datetime + float on odoo

Tags: python, odoo

i want to know `session_finish` from `session_start` + `duration`. the session_start  type is `date` and the duration is `float`.

```
@api.onchange('session_start')
def onchange_session_start(self):
    for record in self:
        if self.session_start is not None : 
            self.session_finish = self.session_start + self.duration
```

Comment: Does this code work? If not, what is the _complete_ error message.

Comment: Float field duration is of datetime type? Ex. duration: 3.5 minutes like

Comment: @DyZ thats is not work:( . this the error : TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, float found

Comment: @rahulmehra the `duration` type is `Float`,, ex. duration 9,5 = 9 hour 30 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert duration then add it to `session_start` as pointed by [@Burmese pythis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48801111/the-way-to-get-a-datetime-from-datetime-float-on-odoo/48803909#48803909):

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    _inherit = "test.model"

    @api.onchange('session_start')
    def onchange_session_start(self):
        if self.session_start:
            session_start = fields.Datetime.from_string(self.session_start)
            interval = datetime.timedelta(seconds=(self.duration * 3600))
            self.session_finish = fields.Datetime.to_string(session_start + interval)

    session_start = fields.Datetime("Session start")
    duration = fields.Float("Duration")
    session_finish = fields.Datetime("Session end")
```

Answer (score 0):

if the session start is a datetime object then you can add the duration using timedelta function

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime(100,1,1,11,34,59)
b = a + datetime.timedelta(0,3) # days, seconds, then other fields.
```

if not then convert the data to datetime

Comment: `datetime.datetime(100,1,1,11,34,59)` can u explain this number ??

Comment: this is the format of datetime object
 import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
output: datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 15, 15, 9, 54, 556721)

Comment: datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[,tzinfo]]]]])

Comment: okaay, but can u give example with my case?, the datetime is not datetime.now() , but i have `session_start` . thank u ^_^

Comment: the field `session_start` type  is datetime

Comment: and the field `duration` is float